# How to create a new pandas column based on an existing column?

Tags: python, pandas

In summary, I'm trying to create a new column from an existing column, but I keep getting warning.
I read data from listings for Airbnb, and I'm trying to create a new column based on 'transit' column containing the word 'subway'.

```
def extract(row, s):
    if type(row['transit']) == float:
        return 0
    if s in row['transit']:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
df = pd.read_csv('listings.csv')
df1 = df[['transit', 'minimum_nights', 'price', 'reviews_per_month']]
df1['subway'] = df1.apply(extract, s='subway', axis=1)
```

I understand python doesn't particularly like the assignment on the last line, but I don't get the logic behind it in this case. I also tried using 'loc' and 'copy' but still got an error. What's the best way to address this warning:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:55: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Use `df1 = df[['transit', 'minimum_nights', 'price', 'reviews_per_month']].copy()`

Comment: I saw the related question, but I didn't see the answer with .copy() as it was buried under more popular answer. That explains.